# Unable to log in to time capsule wired to an router after reconfiguring that router

Tags: wifi, airport, time-capsule

Short: Ever since I reconfigured my netgear router, I haven't been able to log in wirelessly from Win7/Airport to a time capsule (TC) that is cabled into my netgear router.  I think the problem is that I had previously, years ago, configured the TC to have an fixed IP, and now (after giving the netgear a new IP during reconfig) that IP is out of range.

On launch, Airport find the TC and shows it to have the old IP.  When I click manual setup, the error message -6753 "*An error occurred while trying to access the Apple wireless device. Make sure your network connection is valid and try again*."

How can I login to the TC short of resetting the TC to factory? (and lose its config).

Long:
I have a time capsule (TC) plugged into my main router (netgear). I use it as a wifi router and administrate the TC wirelessly under Win7 using the AirPort Utility.  I have the TC configured to only accept connections from a list of MACs.

I can no longer login into the time capsule from Win7.

This started after I changed the IP address of the netgear router. That caused me to lose all my router settings.  It's reconfigured now.

There are a couple odd things. The TC is handling its wifi connected devices (printers etc) properly.  The netgear router is showing them as connected devices, and I can print from a Win7 machine through the TC to a wifi printer.

Yet the netgear router does not show the TC as being connected. And I cannot log in to the TC wirelessly using AirPort.

I think the problem is that I configured the TC to have an fixed IP, and now (after the netgear reconfig) that IP is out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this is how I ended up logging in to administrate the time-capsule.

I cabled the TC to a laptop using one of the three LAN ports on the TC.  At that point Win7 indicated there was something connected at something like 192.168.1.1, which I suspect is the TC's default IP address.

Using that IP and the existing password, I was able to log in to administrate the TC via AirPort > File > Configure Other.

I suspect that on power-up, TC uses that default IP address until it successfully connects through it's WAN port using DHCP, or in my case, the user-configured fixed IP.

Anyway, with a successful login via AirPort, I was able to update the fixed IP to one that was in the range of the reconfigured netgear router to which it is WAN cabled.